# Is there any way to set lock_timeout on a database or connection string level?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

In SQL 2005/2008 is there any way to set default lock_timeout values.

Anything at the server, database, or connection string level would be great.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but you sure you want to change (lower?) the lock time out and not, say, enable read committed snapshot in the database?

Comment: That's a pretty big change - I'm just looking to catch the rare deadlock in our batch processing

Answer (score 3):

You can't set lock timeout in the connection string, AFAIK. Only with SET LOCK_TIMEOUT.

But surely setting "[CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678265(VS.85).aspx)" would achieve pretty much the same result per connection.

There is also the server level [query wait](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189539.aspx) option set by [sp_configure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx), but I've not used it.

Answer (score 1):

Lock timeout i.e. the amount of time a transaction will wait for a lock before failing is usually an 'application-level' setting, set by the `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` command just after the connection is opened.

According to this JDBC driver [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx), there is also a connection string setting `lockTimeout` which might be what you're looking for, but I haven't tried it for ODBC:

> The number of milliseconds to wait
>   before the database reports a lock
>   time-out. The default behavior is to
>   wait indefinitely. If it is specified,
>   this value is the default for all
>   statements on the connection. Note
>   that Statement.setQueryTimeout() can
>   be used to set the time-out for
>   specific statements. The value can be
>   0, which specifies no wait.

Comment: I have a BI database with lots of "applications" connecting to the DB. Setting it on the client is doable, but real ugly.

Comment: I hear you. We have a similar requirement for security that requires running some code directly after connection establishment.  We built a custom SQL Database provider that our apps use, but it would be easier if MS allowed some global trigger that ran in the users's session context!

Comment: As of this time in Microsoft SQL Server 2014, the behaviour of SET LOCK_TIMEOUT is apparently typical for SET, but is not what the documentation seems to say, being that, you can change the setting in a trigger, in a stored procedure, or in "dynamic SQL" - but the setting only lasts while that particular code is executing.  So a literal trigger in SQL won't do it.  Also, you can't SET this value from a variable. (?)  Which is what I tried, before I tried "dynamic SQL", strike two  ;-)